# forked subworkflows all to run to completion but fail the parent workflow if one or more do fail

Tags: netflix-conductor

consider a case in netflix conductor (or orkes) where 2 subworkflows are forked in paralel. The default behaviour of FORK + SUB_WORKFLOW + JOIN tasks is that if the first subworkflow fails, the second one is aborted midway through execution and CANCELLED. The workaround suggested to run both to completion is to mark both SUBWORKFLOW tasks as optional. However the consequence here is that the parent workflow now ends up always COMPLETED only showing the failed SUB_WORKFLOW as "COMPLETED_WITH_ERRORS".

Is there a simple way to have both subworkflows run to completion but have the parent fail if one or more of the subworkflows fail? It feels like that should be the responsibility of the JOIN task but that one is really not configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a script to complete the join.  This was added recently as a feature - yet to be pushed to upstream OSS but you can try it out at play.orkes.io.

documentation:
https://orkes.io/content/reference-docs/operators/join

(See the last example of using join script)

Comment: Great. Thank you for the answer, looks like what I need.  What version of Orkes was this joinScript parameter introduced?

Comment: Its present now in the latest version at https://play.orkes.io/